# Access calendar events with Microsoft Graph using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory

I am trying to access Outlook Calendar events endpoint
From the following graph API app, with the following permissions Calendar.read & Calendar.ReadWrite

I am getting below Error : 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '2491fc8b-6fab-41bb-90be-759045024960' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1653871f-32b8-4e0e-9fe3-dbefdfee4638",
      "date": "2020-04-29T04:06:48"
    }
  }
}

[image]

Comment: Anywhere i need to register Tenant ID? Please help me if anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, where did you copy the tenant id from ? From azure portal ?

Comment: Hi, I created one app under AAD -> App registration. once registration done it will getting App dashboard, here i am able to see : Directory (tenant) ID.

Comment: Yes i am copy the tenant ID azure portal only(AAD -> App registration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Azure AD doesn't have O365 subscription. I created an Azure AD tenant which doesn't have O365 subscription and got the same error with yours.

Apart from this, if you resolve the O365 subscription problem later, you still need to do some change on your request. According to the screenshots you provided, you get the access token by "client_credentials" grant flow, so the access token is application identity but not user identity. So you can't use `me` in your graph api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`. We should request the graph api by:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Suggestion, I change my URL : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/prasad.dara@outlook.com/events instead of 'me' i put my id, Got the same error. Like :

{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '2491fc8b-6fab-41bb-90be-759045024960' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "68fb4bfe-e47d-4e3d-a389-571795c1c4be",
      "date": "2020-04-29T10:46:52"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Is it mandatory to do Office 365 Subscription to access calendar Events?(Like Create event, Get Free/Busy Hours)

Comment: @daranagaanjaniprasad Yes, change `me` to `users/{id}` is the problem in your request, but O365 subscription is necessary precondition.

Comment: Thanks Hury, Now the problem is resolved i replaced me to users/{id} & i used Microsoft developer account without subscription also, I am able to access calendar events.

Thanks for the quick reply it will reduce my time efforts.

Comment: @daranagaanjaniprasad That's great. Could you please mark the answer as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: Sure, i will do now.